# Is there a github api endpoint to give Team access to a repo?

Tags: github, github-api

It is possible to add collaborators via the api as described here: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-user-as-a-collaborator

Endpoint: `/repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators/:username`

But what about adding team access, which is definitely possible via web interface in "Settings > Collaborators & Teams"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i figured out this CAN be done via the api in this way, it just requires headers and data indicating what permissions.:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -u YourUserName:YourPersonalAccessToken -X PUT -d '{"permission":"write"}' https://api.github.com/teams/$team_id/repos/$org_name/$repo
```

Alternatively, in Python:

```
import requests, json

data = json.dumps({"permission": 'read'}) . #could be 'write', etc..
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json, text/plain, */*'
}
auth_tuple = (username, access_token)
url = f"https://api.github.com/teams/{team_id}/repos/{org_name}/{repo}"
requests.put(url, auth=auth_tuple, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [/teams](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/teams#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions-legacy) endpoints have been deprecated. The new way would be to use the [/orgs/{org}/teams](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/teams#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions) endpoints. A curl request would look like below:

```
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/teams/TEAM_SLUG/repos/OWNER/REPO \
  -d '{"permission":"push"}'
```